# History.js onstatechange does not fire with anchor

Tags: javascript, history.js

Please tell me what do I do wrong.

I'm using History.js HTML5 version. When my url is something like

example.com/?param=1

and I change it to

example.com/?param=2

with History.pushState(...),
everything goes as expected.

But when there's an anchor in my Url (just a normal Anchor that has nothing to do with js) like this:

example.com/?param=1#someanchor

and I change it to

example.com/?param=2#someanchor

The URL in my browser actually changes, but **onstatechange does not fire anymore!** Would you be so kind to let me know how to make onstatechange fire with hash present in my url.

Note: I pass the entire url in pushState() everytime;

I've tried onpopstate. It fires almost always.. Except for the time the URL gets equal to the initial URL.

Comment: come on, guys, I know you know how to fix that :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific event for it: window.onanchorchange